# Onchange of Startdate Calculate the End date

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have two date fields, On change of start date need to populate the End date.

Example: If Start-date is 16 Nov 2020, End date should be auto filled with 23 Nov 2020

Below is the code, End date value is printing correctly, but field value is not changing. Can you help what i am missing here.

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">
 <div class="slds-size_4-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                        <lightning-input type="date" name="startdate" label="Start Date"
                                            onchange={handleChangeDate} value={startdate} message-when-value-missing=" "
                                           >
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-size_4-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                        <lightning-input type="date" name="enddate" label="End Date" value={enddate}
                                            message-when-value-missing=" ">
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-size_4-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                        <lightning-input label="Expected Hours" value={expectedhours}
                                            onchange={handleChange} name="expectedhours" message-when-value-missing=" "
                                            >
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
 handleChange(event) {
        this[event.target.name] = event.detail.value;
        // alert(event.detail.value);
    }

       handleChangeDate(event) {
           this.intervalyType = 'Weekly'
        this.startdate = event.detail.value;
        if (this.intervalyType == 'Weekly' && this.startdate != null) {
            var d = new Date(this.startdate);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            var date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getDate();
            this.enddate = date;
            this.expectedhours = 40;
        }
 
        console.log('Start Date -->' + event.detail.value + '  End Dtae --> ' + this.enddate);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@track enddate` and try!

```
@track enddate;
 handleChangeDate(event) {
           this.intervalyType = 'Weekly'
        this.startdate = event.detail.value;
        if (this.intervalyType == 'Weekly' && this.startdate != null) {
            var d = new Date(this.startdate);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            var date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getDate();
            this.enddate = date;
            this.expectedhours = 40;
        }
 
        console.log('Start Date -->' + event.detail.value + '  End Dtae --> ' + this.enddate);
    }
```